# Fragment lifecycle method sequence

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have attached a fragment at runtime in Activity's onCreate() method. I am trying to understand the sequence of lifecycle method calls on the fragment. However the behavior seems to be inconsistent from what is expected.  I am doing a screen rotation to understand this. The below is the log after screen is rotated. Have put the marker in the log at the point of doubt.
Can someone explain what is happening here?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(tag, "OnCreate()");
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Log.d(tag, "SaveInstanceState is NOT NULL");
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mainFragment = new MainFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, mainFragment, "MainFragment").commit();
    }    

MainFragment﹕ OnDestroy
MainFragment﹕ OnDetach
MainActivity﹕ OnDestroy
MainFragment﹕ onAttach() <<< Getting called before Activity's onCreate()
MainActivity﹕ OnCreate()
MainActivity﹕ SaveInstanceState is NOT NULL
MainFragment﹕ onCreateView() 
MainFragment﹕ SaveInstanceState is NOT NULL
MainFragment﹕ onAttach() <<<<<< onAttach() on Fragment called again
MainFragment﹕ onCreateView() <<<<<<< onCreateView() on Fragment again.
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the Fragment lifecycle:

[image: Here is the Fragment Lifecycle]

As per your question, when the screen is rotated, it means that the fragment and activities need to be reloaded or "recreated". If you follow the lifecycle image, you will see that Fragment is first destroyed (because it was rotated), then detached. The activity gets detached next.

Then the fragment is attached (the fragment is the object that is called before the Activity). Thereafter the activity is created.

Read up on the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) for a better understanding, but above answers your doubts.